# How to mock methods for writing unit tests in nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I am writing unit tests in nodejs using mocha and sinon.js. I am facing issues in mocking the dependencies. So I want to test method1() which internally calls method2(). I want to mock the method2(). I am using this using sinon.stub() as shown in the code snippet below. But when I run the test case, the actual method is getting called instead of the stubbed one.
What am I doing wrong here?

```
    fileA.js

    async function method1() {
        // do something
        await method2()
    }

    async function method2() {
        // do something
    }


    fileA.test.js

    fileA = require('./fileA')

    sinon.stub(fileA, 'method2').callsFake(fakeFn() {
        // do something else
    })

    fileA.method1()
```

Comment: Using this for calling method2 solved my probelm..

fileA.js

`async function method1() {
        // do something
        await this.method2()
    }`

And I don't understand why.. :(